# How to render the "disabled" HTML attribute on server with React.js 16?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I just updated to `React.js 16` and I am having a hard time using a simples HTML attribute in a `button`. This is my code:

```
const disabled = this.props.disabled;
console.log(disabled);
return <button id="my-id" disabled={disabled}>Click!</button>;
```

The `console.log` logs `true` on the frontend and `false` on the backend. And on the browser console I am getting this: `Warning: Prop 'disabled' did not match. Server: "null" Client: "true"`.

In the React Chrome Extension I can see that the prop is actually set to `true`, so it should work. It only works if I force it to change to `false` and then back to `true` in the frontend.

[image: sorcery]

This used to work with `React.js 15.5.4`. What am I doing wrong / what changed in `React.js 16`?

Comment: I'd ask why `this.props.disabled` is null on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After migrating to `React.js 16` we started using `hydrate` for the frontend, and the element was not being updated, which is a expected behaviour.

The problem was actually in `redux-form` as reported here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2610

After adding a extra condition of `pristine` everything works fine now.